# why Link inside tab not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have used JQuery UI tabs and my tabs are working fine. please see the code below.

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Register User</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Forgot Password </a></li>


</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content clearfix">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div class="login-form">
                <div class="username-bg"><input name="a" type="text" value="username" /><img src="images/user-icon.png" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="password-bg"><input name="a" type="password" value="password" /><img src="images/password-icon.png" alt="" /></div>
                <a href="#tab3" class="login-text">Lost Your Password ?</a>
                <a href="preprints.html" class="signup"></a>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content ">
        <h2>Register User</h2>
        <div class="login-form">
                <div class="username-bg " ><input name="a" type="text" value="username" required  /><img src="images/user-icon.png" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="password-bg"><input name="a" type="password" value="password" /><img src="images/password-icon.png" alt="" /></div>             
                <a href="#tab3" class="login-text">Lost Your Password ?</a>
                <a href="preprints.html" class="save"></a>          
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
        <h2>Forgot Password</h2>
        <div class="login-form">
                <div class="username-bg"><input name="a" type="text" value="new password" /><img src="images/password-icon.png" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="password-bg"><input name="a" type="text" value="confirm password" /><img src="images/password-icon.png" alt="" /></div>
                <a href="#tab3" class="login-text">Lost Your Password ?</a>
                <a href="preprints.html" class="save"></a>          
        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

The Jquery i used is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

now i want a link inside the tab `Lost Your Password ?` to link to tab3 that is forgot password tab but it is not woking please help. Thanks

Comment: All I see is just HTML, no jQuery

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Give the link inside the tab a new class (e.g. `class="linktab"`) and a data attribute (e.g. `data-tab="3"`) and use something like

```
$('a.linktab').click(function() {
    $('.tabs').tabs('option', 'active', $(this).data('tab'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by the data attribute ?

Comment: change your `<a href="#tab3" class="login-text">Lost Your Password ?</a>` to `<a href="#tab3" class="login-text linktab" data-tab="3">Lost Your Password ?</a>`. With this you store in the link the information which tab the link opens.

Comment: It didn't workout boss. the url is getting appended with #tab3. for other tabs the url is not updating but the tab opens.

Comment: Probably the normal click event of the link is still fired. Add `return false` like in the edited answer.